# Runing network cable near X-Ray equipment

Tags: networking, cable, interference

I was suggested on [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/runing-network-cable-near-x-ray-equipment) to post this here as someone may know the the answer to this question.

My mother runs a small veterinary clinic. She is getting a new X-Ray machine that will need a network connection to send digital copies of the X-Ray to the server. I will be installing a wall plate with a few Ethernet jacks in the X-Ray room.

Do I need to do anything special like shielded cabling for this install? I am not worried about transmission errors that may occur during the split second the X-Ray is active, TCP can fix those, I am concerned about damaging the computer's NIC or router in the wiring closet due to some form of current induction.

The cable will not be running in the direct path of the X-Ray beam just be in wall leading to the room. Am I being overly cautious or is this a legitimate concern? Also if I need to route under the path of the beam for some reason are there any consequences for that?

Comment: Can you link to a PDF of your mom's X-ray machine's installation guide and user manual, so we can read it for you? :-)

Comment: They will have a tech from the company installing the machine (usually the local IT does not do it) all they need is power and network in the room where they will be setting it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard utp (unshielded twisted pair) should be fine.

What you should be aware of is that part of the installation for an x-ray machine should involve installing shielding in the walls of the room where the machine will be located.  This shielding (not the x-rays) may present a problem at some point if you want to provide wifi coverage in the office, as it will completely block an signal from passing through.

Comment: That is the exact reason I am running cabling through the wall, we can not use a wifi bridge to our existing wifi network as the room becomes a big Faraday cage when you close the door (steel plates on all 6 walls. I have conduit that will get me through the wall shielding for the cables.